# Figure (with caption) inside a longtable cell

Tags: latex, longtable

I have a problem running on Latex. I have a huge longtable with an image inside each cell. Each image should have a counter and a caption. I have tried declaring the image as a figure (and it fails compiling) and also declaring it as minipage and using captionof, but as I could see [searching through internet](ftp://ctan.tug.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/caption/caption-eng.pdf), captionof is uncompatible with longtable.

Is there a way to put an image (with its corresponding image counter and text) inside a longtable cell?

Comment: I think you will get a better answer @ http://tex.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1):

Since `\captionof` was uncompatible with `longtable`, we need another way to:

- set the proper counter,
- set the appropiate type (figure or table, as you can use both),
- set the proper title for the image.

For this purpose, I found [this thread](http://newsgroups.derkeiler.com/Archive/Comp/comp.text.tex/2007-12/msg00664.html), and it worked almost perfectly. The only thing not mentioned in the thread is that you have to include the caption-text.sty NOT using `\include{caption-text}`, but `\usepackage{caption-text}`. For the rest, you can follow the instructions at the mentioned thread.